# Differentiate ${\operatorname{Tr}((SS^T)^{-1}A)}$ w.r.t. $S$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, trace

From matrix cookbook (eq. 125) I only know that

$\frac{{\operatorname{Tr}((S^TS)^{-1}A)}}{dS}=-S(S^TS)^{-1}(A+A^T)(S^TS)^{-1}$.

Can anybody tell me what happens to the result if I switch $(S^TS)^{-1}$ to $(SS^T)^{-1}$?

So what is

$\frac{{\operatorname{Tr}((SS^T)^{-1}A)}}{dS}=...$?

*P.S. In general I am also very interested how the authors came up with the solution in eq. 125*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, define a new matrix variable 
$$M=S^TS$$ note that $M$ is symmetric.

Instead of the trace notation, let's use the inner/Frobenius product
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$ which is easier to manipulate algebraically. All of the properties of the Frobenius product follow from the cyclical and transpostional properties of the trace, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
 &A:B  = B:A \cr
 &A:B  = A^T:B^T \cr
 &AB:C  = A:CB^T \cr
}$$

Now re-write the function and find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 f &= A:M^{-1} \cr
\cr
df
 &= -A:M^{-1}\,dM\,M^{-1} \cr
 &= -M^{-1}AM^{-1}:dM \cr
 &= -(S^TS)^{-1}A(S^TS)^{-1}:d(S^TS) \cr
 &= -(S^TS)^{-1}A(S^TS)^{-1}:(dS^T\,S+S^T\,dS) \cr
 &= -(S^TS)^{-1}(A+A^T)(S^TS)^{-1}:S^T\,dS \cr
 &= -S(S^TS)^{-1}(A+A^T)(S^TS)^{-1}:dS \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}
  &= -S(S^TS)^{-1}(A+A^T)(S^TS)^{-1} \cr
\cr
}$$ 
So that's where the result you quoted comes from -- but notice that it's off by a factor of 2. The factor of 2 is likely due to the fact that when $A$ is symmetric then $A+A^T=2A$, but this result was incompletely substituted.

Now let's change the definition of $M$ to
$$M=SS^T$$
Picking up the differential at the point where it's still in terms of $M$, we can substitute the new definition to get the answer to your question 
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= -M^{-1}AM^{-1}:dM \cr
 &= -(SS^T)^{-1}A(SS^T)^{-1}:d(SS^T) \cr
 &= -(SS^T)^{-1}A(SS^T)^{-1}:(dS\,S^T+S\,dS^T) \cr
 &= -(SS^T)^{-1}(A+A^T)(SS^T)^{-1}:dS\,S^T \cr
 &= -(SS^T)^{-1}(A+A^T)(SS^T)^{-1}S:dS \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial S}
  &= -(SS^T)^{-1}(A+A^T)(SS^T)^{-1}S \cr
\cr
}$$

Comment: thank you very very much. the leading 2 is wrong. I made a mistake there! I will edit this immediately.

Comment: By the way is there some good textbook about an introduction of the frobenius product and its usage for derivatives?

Comment: In another example I figured out, that $S$ is a lower triangular matrix with 1s on the diagonal. Is it possible to use this structural knowledge for the derivative?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is - Replacing $\mathrm S$ by $\mathrm S^{\mathrm T}$. Therefore just replace $\mathrm S \rightarrow \mathrm S^{\mathrm T}$ everywhere to get the result.

Comment: But then I get my derivative w.r.t. $S^T$ and not to $S$?